# Show active navigation for current page

Tags: php

i'm having some problems with my html, php code. With this code, my nav will show the active li but the other pages which are not active won't have style or links.

```
    <!--/. PHP "active" -->
    <?php
    $current_url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $active = "class=\"active-menu\"";
    ?>
    <!--/. PHP "active" -->

    <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">
                <li>
                    <?php if ($current_url == "home.php") { ?>
                    <a <?php echo $active;?> href="home.php"><?php } ?><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <?php if ($current_url == "new.php") { ?>
                    <a <?php echo $active;?> href="new.php"><?php } ?><i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i> Nieuw item toevoegen</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <?php if ($current_url == "show.php") { ?>
                    <a <?php echo $active;?> href="show.php"><?php } ?><i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i> Bekijk inventaris</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <?php if ($current_url == "profile.php") { ?>
                    <a <?php echo $active;?> href="profile.php"><?php } ?><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Gebruikersprofiel</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Gebruikers<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Beheerders</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">ICT - Verantwoordelijken</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Raadplegers</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <?php if ($current_url == "empty.php") { ?>
                    <a <?php echo $active;?> href="empty.php"><?php } ?><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i> Lege pagina</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </nav>
```

the pages with no styling will also not have a link. The active-menu class has the styling.

Comment: That makes totally sense. Look at your IF-statements. Lets say, you're on new.php. So the current_url = home.php will be false - you're not displaying a link at all. Simply add a else-condition. In the IF, you're adding the $active, in the else you're not adding it but you still put there the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition it is wrong.

Try something like this in every `<li>`.

```
<li>
    <a <?php echo $current_url == "home.php" ? $active : ''; ?> href="home.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
     <a href="new.php" <?php if ($current_url == "new.php") {echo $active;}?>>
     <i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i> Nieuw item toevoegen
     </a>
</li>
```

Put your list like this

Answer (score 0):

You should make another class, like $not_active = "class=\"not-active-menu\"";
And add that to your code

```
<li>
     <a href="something.php" <?php if ($current_url == "something.php") {echo $active;} else { echo $not_active; }?>>
     <i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i> something
     </a>
</li>
```